# Spendthrift vs Thrifty - origins

Tags: meaning, etymology, antonyms

I have always been curious to understand the origin of these two seemingly similar words. Looking at them for the first time, I thought they were synonyms, but ever since I learned of their existence, their meanings only serve to confuse me further.

Does anybody know how these words came into being, and how they ended up becoming antonyms despite (possibly) stemming from the same word root?

Comment: The following link provides a possible answer, but are there other reasons?
http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-spe1.htm

Comment: I think it goes to show that the order of words can matter. I too was confused by this compound word, because it would seem logically that a "spendthrift" (spends all their money) would be equivalent to a "thrifty spender" (saves their money). According to OED, the earliest definitions (~1300) of thrift meant wealth, prosperity and fortune. Hence a "spend+thrift" is someone who spends their fortune. Also in OED, the meaning of being frugal seemed to come about 2 centuries later. Maybe the "spendthrift" was formed with the original meaning and not the later.

Comment: Of course they're not synonymous.  The first is a noun.  The second is an adjective.  Moreover, they don't attribute antithetical meanings to "thrift."  "Thrift" conveys conserved money, savings.  Therefore, "thrifty" conveys describing someone or something as having a money-saving nature, while "spendthrift" conveys a person who *spends* their *thrift*, someone who blows their would-be savings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[thrift](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=thrift&searchmode=none) originally meant your savings (a noun), not the adjective "to save or spend carefully".

> c.1300, *fact or condition of thriving,* also "prosperity, savings," from Middle English *thriven* "to thrive", influenced by (or from) Old Norse *þrift*, variant of *þrif* "prosperity,"...
>
> The sense of thriving or prosperity preceded the idea that prosperity was obtained by *thriftiness*, which was first recorded in the sense of *habit of saving, economy* in the 1520s.

*Spend* meaning to pay money (1125–75); Middle English *spenden* < Latin expendere  to pay out, expend) is itself an earlier form spend referring to labor, thoughts, time, etc. (to spend oneself), attested from c.1300.

[spendthrift](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=spendthrift&searchmode=none) from c.1600, means spend (**v.**) + thrift (**n.**) in sense of "savings, profits, wealth." Replaced earlier scattergood (1570s) and spend-all (1550s). From c.1600 as an adjective.

So you are spending your savings or wealth (what makes you prosperous.)

Synonyms are dingthrift and scattergood.

Answer (score 1):

I copy and paste [this article](http://michiganradio.org/post/why-spendthrift-isnt-thrifty) with an audio clip that differs from the text beneath and appears not transcribed.

---

Spendthrifts are more spendy than thrifty, so the word spendthrift doesn’t seem to make much sense.

This week on *That’s What They Say,* host Rina Miller and University of Michigan English Professor [Anne Curzan](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~acurzan/) discuss the seemingly oxymoronic word spendthrift.

While *thrifty* refers to being economical with money, *spendthrift* means the exact opposite—someone who spends money irresponsibly. Curzan explores the etymology of *thrifty* to get to the bottom of *spendthrift.*

“*Thrifty* comes from the word *thrive*, meaning ‘to prosper,’” Curzan explains. “Starting in the 16th century, it also means that someone is thrifty, or frugal.”

However, it is the noun *thrift,* not the adjective *thrifty,* which led to *spendthrift*. *Thrift* can refer to someone’s earnings, which makes a *spendthrift* someone who spends his or her income.

When looking up spendthrift, Curzan also found the synonym *dingthrift*.

“The *ding* in *dingthrift* is the same ding we have now, for example, if someone dings your car,” Curzan describes. While the word appears to be obsolete, Curzan hopes Michigan Radio listeners can bring it back.

Will you add *dingthrift* to your vocabulary? What out-of-date words do you want to resurrect? Let us know by writing a comment below.